# Why faces disappeared and is it possible to fix this?

Tags: edit-mode, faces, extrude

I'm building a dinosaur legs by using extrusion. At some point, some of the bottom faces disappeared and I'm unable to continue building the legs. Is it possible to bring them back? Or start over? My file: https://workupload.com/file/hZnGM58CD4L [image]

Comment: maybe Alt + H ?

Comment: Tried that, and also, The Make Normals Consistent commend.  Didn't help

Comment: Please share your Blend file so that we can see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Okay, thanks, edited.

Comment: All is fine for me with this file...

Comment: Strange, as I'm trying to extrude the leg downwards further and there's no face to select, like in the picture.

Comment: have you tried to close and reopen the file?

Comment: yes, I tried :D

Comment: would it be somehow possible to delete the whole leg and leave just the body without any distortion to it?  I would start over from there.

Comment: That file is fine here too. As downloaded, your file loads with just a single edge selected on the end of the foot. If you Shift-Click the other 3 edges round that foot you can extrude as normal, or switching to Face mode (3 on the main keyboard) lets you select the face at the end of the foot and extrude that. - Of course you're also in wireframe view which might be confusing you too? - Hit Z > Solid or Shift-Z to toggle.

Comment: That's the thing, when I'm in the Face mode, I can't see the face that I need to select. Just blank space there

Comment: Which foot are you trying to select the face on, left or right? You'll only be able to select the left one because the right one is mirrored.

Comment: Yes, doing everything on the left one. No worries, reached the desired result by doing the legs a bit differently, but should work. Thanks for trying to help.